# Query to generate a list of date times

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'd like to build a query that has some variables named:

```
    EndDate --this is a date
    LookBackDays --this is an integer
    Interval -- this is an interval in SECONDS
    Name -- this is  a string
   open -this is a string and is hours and minutes  in 24HH
   close - this is string and is hours and minutes in 24HH
```

let's say I set my varaibles to:

```
EndDate to 7/4
LookBackDays  = 3
Inteval = 300 seconds
Name = "BOB"
open = "09:00"
close = "13:00"
```

I then want to generate a list of dates from the Endate-LookbackDays to the EndDate that will look like

That will look like

```
  Date     Open      Close       Name
7/1/2015   09:00 AM    13:00 PM    Bob
7/2/2015   09:00 AM    13:00 PM    Bob
7/3/2015   09:00 AM    13:00 PM    Bob
7/4/2015   09:00 AM    13:00 PM    Bob
....
....
```

Then for each Date I'd like to add additional rows using the Interval parameter where for each row I break up the time interval from the open time to the close time into buckets based on the interval so for an interval of 300 seconds the results would be:

```
   date          oepn                close             name    IntervalEnd
 7/1/2015    7/1/2015 09:00 AM   7/1/2015 13:00 PM    Bob        09:05 AM
 7/1/2015   7/1/2015 09:00 AM   7/1/2015 13:00 PM    Bob        09:10 AM
 7/1/2015  7/1/2015 09:00 AM   7/1/2015 13:00 PM    Bob        09:15 AM
 7/1/2015  7/1/2015 09:00 AM    7/1/2015 13:00 PM    Bob        09:20 AM
 7/1/2015  7/1/2015 09:00 AM   7/1/2015 13:00 PM    Bob        09:25 AM
....
....
 7/1/2015   09:00 AM   7/1/2015 13:00 PM    Bob       7/1/2015 12:55 PM
 7/1/2015   09:00 AM   7/1/2015 13:00 PM    Bob       7/1/2015 01:00 PM
 **7/2/2015**  7/2/2015 09:00 AM   7/2/2015 13:00 PM    Bob        09:05 AM
 7/2/2015  7/2/2015 09:00 AM   7/2/2015 13:00 PM    Bob        09:10 AM
 7/2/2015  7/2/2015 09:00 AM   7/2/2015 13:00 PM    Bob        09:15 AM
 7/2/2015  7/2/2015 09:00 AM   7/2/2015 13:00 PM    Bob        09:20 AM
 7/2/2015  7/2/2015 09:00 AM   7/2/2015 13:00 PM    Bob        09:25 AM
....
....
 7/2/2015  7/2/2015 09:00 AM   7/2/2015 13:00 PM    Bob        12:55 PM
 7/2/2015  7/2/2015 09:00 AM   7/2/2015 13:00 PM    Bob        01:00 PM
```

...and so on for each day. So basically I am taking each day and exapanding it into multiple buckets

Comment: What are you expecting the procedure to return as an `out` parameter?  A `sys_refcursor`?  A collection?  Something else?  That's certainly possible.  But aren't you going to want to do something with this result like join it to another table in order to get counts by period?  If so, you'd really want this to be implemented as a pipelined table function.

Comment: Please see edit it does not have to be a stored procedure. It should just be a query

Comment: Please see edit I added dates to output not jsut times

Comment: Does "a query" mean that you now want to avoid using PL/SQL and do everything in SQL?  A pipelined table function isn't normally considered a "query" though it can be used in a data source in a `select` statement.

Comment: I just mean an oracle query using temporary tables if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cross join two hierarchical queries, like here:

```
with par as (
  select date '2015-07-04' enddate, 3 LookBackDays, 300 inteval, 'Bob' Name, 
         '09:00' open, '13:00' close from dual),
t1 as (
  select to_char(enddate-level+1, 'yyyy-mm-dd') dt, name, open, close from par
    connect by level <= LookBackDays + 1 ),
t2 as (
  select to_char(to_date(open, 'hh24:mi') + (level) * inteval / (24*60*60), 'hh24:mi') tm
    from par
    connect by to_date(open, 'hh24:mi') + level * inteval / (24*60*60) 
               <= to_date(close, 'hh24:mi') )
select to_date(dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd') dt, 
       to_date(dt||' '||open, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') open, 
       to_date(dt||' '||close, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') close, name, 
       to_date(dt||' '||tm, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') IntervalEnd
  from t1 cross join t2 order by dt, tm
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/3308)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @ponder works great. Is it possible to add a column to the output that is the Time of the IntervalEND column. So a new column "BucketEndTime"  = "09:05:00 AM", "09:10:00 AM",...."12:55:00 PM"...etc for each row.

Comment: Yes, just add column: `to_char(to_date(dt||' '||tm, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'hh:mi:ss am') BucketEndTime` like in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/3309).

Comment: can you take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886989/generate-sequence-of-dates-and-time

Comment: As for me - you need this query with [lag()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) function: 
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/3336) I'm slightly too tired today to analyze any nuances, but it should do the trick.
Anyway it's good, that you asked new question, you may get better answers there.